# Using David Piegza's 3D Force-Directed Graph for LARGE Data; visualization is too slow

Tags: three.js

I am using David Piegza's open source code for visualizing a 3D Force-Directed graph using Three.js. The source code can be found here: https://github.com/davidpiegza/Graph-Visualization

When I start visualizing 2,000+ nodes, things get VERY slow. The visualization takes 30 seconds or so to load, and rotating and panning has a long delay. What could be the cause of this? The force-directed algorithm? Can Javascript handle this many nodes in a force-directed, 3D graph? Is there some sort of back-face culling algorithm I can use for 3D, force-directed graphs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess force-directed layout algorythm is not main problem here. The main one is GPU resources. I'm developing a 2D webgl graph now, and use particles for displaying nodes (this is much faster than drawing cubes). And even such realization has GPU limitations. You can try to zoom graph as much as possible and if the fps rate will increase than my suggestion is right (fewer objects you see on the screen - faster GPU working).

Comment: Good call, it's the GPU limitations. I'll start working on a work around. It sounds like using particles, geometry merging, and caching are crucial.

Comment: P.S. Let me know how it goes! I would like to see your solution one day.

Comment: Main problem for performance are edges and labels. Currently I'm using one Mesh for all lines (on close distance - to achieve line thickness), Three.Lines (on far distance) and particlesystems for nodes. I can build interactive grpah with 10k nodes / 20k edges with 30 fps on my GeForce GTS250, but there are still lots of things to be done. I'll try to participate with my library on this GSoC.

Comment: Ah, I wish I was at that point. Right now I have 2k nodes and 2k edges with 10 fps. It seems that Three.js has frustum culling built in; it may be time for me to switch to particles.

Comment: @dlsoVi If you have anything you could tell me, I would appreciate it. I'm on a tight deadline to get something working. I switched to particles with **worse** performance.

Comment: @LearningPython it's almost impossible to help you here, I can't even see your code. I'm sure that your problem is not in particles, because if you use ParticleSystem for nodes - you have only 1 point per object, this is very fast solution (you can see 500k particles on the screen with 60 fps). You can create new question with link to your working code example, and I'll take a look on it.

Comment: @dlsoVi Here's the repository, inside LeapVis1.2 if you open index.html with Firefox the particle vis should load.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776405/three-js-particles-load-insanely-slow-whats-causing-the-slowness-and-massive-c