# Three.js particles load insanely slow? What's causing the slowness and massive cut in FPS? (From 60+ fps to 1-2 fps)

Tags: graph, 3d, three.js

I can't figure out what's slowing down my visualization. Ideally, I would like 60 fps. Not 1 fps or 2 fps.

Here are the repositories. For the first one, inside LeapVis1.2, if you open index.html with Firefox after you download the folder the vis should load.
[Non-Particles](https://github.com/Glchriste/JSGraphVis)

For the repository that uses particles, open canvas_particles_random.html in Firefox.
[Particles (Even slower)](https://github.com/Glchriste/JSParticleGraphVIs)

Comment: Post a demo on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Alright. I'm not experienced with jsfiddle, but I'll try and get it set up.

Comment: This isn't loading the visualization for some reason, but it does have the code for the particles visualization. http://jsfiddle.net/5zpqp/

Comment: I am guessing the d.json can't be loaded because you are trying to load it from jsfiddle and not from wherever it resides.

Answer (score 2):

First of all this is continuation of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371176/using-david-piegzas-3d-force-directed-graph-for-large-data-visualization-is-to/15386837?noredirect=1#comment22427449_15386837). The reason of its slowness is because your are using CanvasRenderer instead of WebGLRenderer. I guess you've misunderstood me. In three.js there are two objects: Particle - for canvas and ParticleSystem - for webgl. I've never ment to use canvas, because it is very slow in comparison with webgl.

Comment: Yep, there's a massive difference. Wow. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: For anyone looking for a solution in the future, I don't have graph code with particles working yet. However, you can easily get this code working offline if you save a few files from the domain. It's a good, working example, though not a graph: http://oos.moxiecode.com/js_webgl/particles_morph/

Comment: I know this question is rather old, but did you manage to speed-up your edges as well? In my current project they are still geometrie, slowing everything down considerably.